# Will Muslims be punished In the hereafter?

Tags: jannah, jahannam, judgements

AsSalamOAlaykum to all of you!

I want to ask this question as it was coming in my head again and again. It has been a few months before when I learned about it but I don't really get it. I hope that I will get some useful answers. The question is:

Will all the Muslims (except the non-Muslims who will go to hell) except Prophets and those buried in Jannat-ul-Maula and Jannat-ul-Baqi as they will go to Paradise without any test, go to hell for a short period of time to wash off all their sins to get pure of sins before entering Paradise and then enter Paradise?

Please add some Hadis and Quranic Verses in your answers.

Wa Alaikum As Salam

Comment: How do you know those buried in Jannat-ul-Maula and Jannat-ul-Baqi will go to paradise? We only know that the Prophets and the Khatamun Nabiyeen will certainly go to Paradise?

Comment: i heard about it somewhere but I do agree with that for Jannat-ul-Baqi and i think Jannat-ul-Maula also goes for that https://www.islamiclandmarks.com/madinah-other/jannatul-baqi

Comment: Wa Alaikum As Salam

Comment: I wont for get your edits on my question @III-AK-III
Jazak Allah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not everyone goes to Hell first.

1. For example, some people are already forgiven and [with their Lord](https://quran.com/3/169).
2. Another example... Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) said,

   > "My Lord promised me that seventy thousand of my Ummah shall be admitted into Paradise without a reckoning against them, Nor any punishment" - [Tirmidhi 2437](https://sunnah.com/urn/677430).

Who are these seventy thousand people? They are people whose Tawheed
    (ie., belief in the Oneness of God) is so perfect that they don't
    ask others for Ruqyah, don't believe in evil omens) and they put
    their full trust in Allah. [Ref. [Bukhari]](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/61).

The above applies to people who aren't even brought to account. They go straight to Jannah, iA.

What about those who do have to account on Judgement Day? Allah (ﷻ) said,

> "Then as for one whose scales are heavy [with good deeds], He will be in a pleasant life. But as for one whose scales are light, His refuge will be an abyss (Hell) - [Qur'an 101:6-9](https://quran.com/101/6-9).

Muslims whose sins outweigh their good will be subject to punishment in Hell for the purposes of purification. If you don't want to go to Hell first, then repent sincerely and do good deeds so that your good outweighs your bad deeds. SubhanAllah.

Comment: Jazak Allah @Love Strength يا رب العالمين for the help. As there are no competing answers like yours so well explaining I guess the tick goes for you until there are some more better answers and it also answered in what I was a little confused